# How to count word length (K&R book exercise)

Tags: c

I am going through Kerninghan & Ritchie's "C Programming Language" 2nd edition and am stuck on exercises 1-13 and 1-14, which involves counting word length and character occurrences, respectively. I am just testing for now (no idea how to print the histogram, but I might attempt that later) and counting word length just isn't working for me. I appear to be incrementing my array positions too much, but why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int array[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int counter, c, position;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c == ' '){
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            counter ++;
            array[counter] += 1;
        }
    }
    position = 0;
    for (position = 0; position < 10; ++position){
        printf("%d", array[position]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
Sample input: "o tw thr"

Sample output- "0321000000"

Comment: What is the initial value of `counter`?

Comment: So what is this code supposed to do, after all? This counts neither the occurrences of individual characters, nor the length of the words on a line.

Comment: Unassigned, because I'm obviously retarded.

This code is supposed to count the length of words. The array printing at the bottom is to print how many times a word with length occurred. Here is some updates http://ideone.com/gLgY2z

Comment: Your title should reflect the question your asking.

Comment: Please give this question an appropriate title. Think of *everyone else* who's visiting this website.

Comment: array[counter] += 1; ... "I do not think it means what you think it means."

Comment: What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Question edited. My expected output is how many times a word with a specific length occurs.

Comment: Your description says you need to count "word length and character occurrences" -- character occurrence means the number of times a particular character occurs, e.g. 'z' appears 0 times in this comment. From your preceding comment, I think you mean "word length and number of times a word of a specific length occurs."

Comment: @user3765259 check my answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: @user3765259-I hope my answer helps you understand how it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [code](http://ideone.com/SJFQ0X) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
int array[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int counter=0, c, position;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
        array[counter]++;
        counter = 0;
    } else {
        if(counter<9) {
            counter ++;
        }
    }
}
if(counter!=0) {
    array[counter]++;
}
for (position = 0; position < 10; ++position){
    printf("%d ", array[position]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with your code was that whenever a character was appearing, you were incrementing an array position. What is needed is to wait till the word is finished and as soon as we encounter " ", we increment the word length position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize counter like this:

```
counter = 0;
```

before using it.